# Why is it that any conductor is an equipotential?

Tags: electrostatics, voltage

According to [Prof. Lewin's lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QpVxj3XrLgk#t=37m40s) the metals (I extrapolate to conductors) are equipotentials; why is this?

I can understand that the Electric Field all along the metal is zero, but not the equipotential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Electric field is minus the potential gradient.  So electric field equal to zero means that the potential gradient is zero and hence the potential is constant.